# How to hide subcomponents in design time in Structure view panel when creating own component (hide <components[1]>)

Tags: delphi

I'm creating simple component inherited from TControl (Firemonkey).
In constructor I wrote :

```
constructor TControl1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

  fTest := TLayout.Create(Self);
  fTest.Parent := Self;
end;
```

How when I place this component to the form, Structure list shows Tlayout as subcomponent as <components[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zkcb.png)>. How can I hide it? 
See screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use

1. `SetSubComponent(True);`
2. `Owner` must be `Self`

```
constructor TControl1.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

  fTest := TLayout.Create(Self);
  fTest.SetSubComponent(True);
  fTest.Parent := Self;
end;
```

Here is also similar question:

[How to disable child controls at design-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209523/)