# Hiding subcomponents at design time in Structure view panel

Tags: delphi, components

I'm referring to these:

[How to hide subcomponents in design time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50202133/how-to-hide-subcomponents-in-design-time-in-structure-view-panel-when-creating-o)

[How to disable child controls at design-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209523/how-to-disable-child-controls-at-design-time)

I also have the same problem while creating a TFloatAnimation as subcomponent despite putting the above suggested lines correctly

```
FloatAnimation2:= TFloatAnimation.Create(self);
FloatAnimation2.Parent:= Self;
FloatAnimation2.SetSubComponent(True);
FloatAnimation2.Enabled:= true;
FloatAnimation2.PropertyName:= 'Scale.Y';
FloatAnimation2.StartValue:= 1;
FloatAnimation2.StopValue:=  FGrowFactor;
FloatAnimation2.Inverse:=  true;
FloatAnimation2.Interpolation:= TInterpolationType.Linear;
FloatAnimation2.Trigger:= 'IsMouseOver=true';
FloatAnimation2.TriggerInverse:= 'IsMouseOver=false';
```

[image]

In addition, as you can see, despite having only two TFloatAnimation created, I get many more in the
structure view panel.
What should I do to correct that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding

```
FloatAnimation1.Stored:= False;
```

I don't see anymore the sub-components