# Why doesn't my run-time-created component appear on the form?

Tags: delphi

I am testing the example that came from this Q&A [Component Creation - Joining Components Together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479872/component-creation-joining-components-together) to learn how to create a custom/composite component.

While the installed component from the example works dragging on to the form, I can't seem to create it at run time.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
MyPanel2 : TMyPanel;
begin
MyPanel2 := TMyPanel.Create(Form1);
With MyPanel2 do
  begin
    Left := 10;
    Top := 10;
    Width := 400;
    Height := 400;
    Visible := True;
    Image.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\test.png');
  end;
end;
```

I tried both self and Form1 as the owner.  Played with properties of both the panel and the image.

Just not sure what I am doing wrong.  No errors except when I forgot to add pngimage to my uses.  Steps through the code just fine, nothing visually occurs for the run time creation.

Comment: I mentioned `Parent` in my final comment to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14554428/62576). :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set [`Parent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Parent) in the runtime code.

```
MyPanel2 := TMyPanel.Create(Self);
with MyPanel2 do
begin
  Parent := Self;//oops, you forgot to set this
  SetBounds(10, 10, 400, 400);
  Image.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\test.png');
end;
```

The code in your question won't result in the control showing for a plain vanilla `TPanel`, or indeed any control.

From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Parent), with my emphasis:

> Specifies the parent of the control.
>
> Use the Parent property to get or set the parent of the control. The
>   parent of a control is the control that contains it. For example, if
>   an application includes three radio buttons in a group box, the group
>   box is the parent of the three radio buttons, and the radio buttons
>   are the child controls of the group box.
>
> To serve as a parent, a control must be an instance of a TWinControl
>   descendant.
>
> **When creating a new control at run time, assign a Parent property
>   value for the new control**. Usually, this is a form, panel, group box,
>   or a control that is designed to contain another. Changing the parent
>   of a control moves the control onscreen so that it is displayed within
>   the new parent. When the parent control moves, the child moves with
>   the parent.

Comment: DOH! LOL.  Alright it won't let me set the answer yet but when it does you have it.  Glad people are here to answer even the dumbest of questions.  Phew now the learning can begin.

Comment: +1. I mentioned this specifically in my last comment to the poster's [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14554428/62576). Guess I didn't emphasize it enough. :-)